# C++ can not build simple test program after update (Ubuntu 22.04/ROS 2 Rolling)

Tags: ros, c++, colcon

I just updated my Ubuntu 22.04 installation with ROS 2 rolling on it and now when I try to rebuild my ROS packages I get an error message that it can't compile a simple test program:

```
CMake Error at /home/john/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:60 (message):
 The C++ compiler

   "/usr/bin/c++"

 is not able to compile a simple test program.

 It fails with the following output:

   Change Dir: '/home/john/floyd2_ws/build/moveit_msgs/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-cr7niU'
   
   Run Build Command(s): /home/john/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cmake/data/bin/cmake -E env VERBOSE=1 /usr/bin/gmake -f Makefile cmTC_00a33/fast
   /usr/bin/gmake  -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_00a33.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_00a33.dir/build
   gmake[1]: Entering directory '/home/john/floyd2_ws/build/moveit_msgs/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-cr7niU'
   Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_00a33.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o
   /usr/bin/c++   w  -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_00a33.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -c /home/john/floyd2_ws/build/moveit_msgs/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-cr7niU/testCXXCompiler.cxx
   c++: warning: w: linker input file unused because linking not done
   c++: error: w: linker input file not found: No such file or directory
   gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_00a33.dir/build.make:78: CMakeFiles/cmTC_00a33.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o] Error 1
   gmake[1]: *** Deleting file 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_00a33.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o'
   gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/home/john/floyd2_ws/build/moveit_msgs/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-cr7niU'
   gmake: *** [Makefile:127: cmTC_00a33/fast] Error 2
   
   

 

 CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
 CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)
```

I'm at a complete loss as to what to do.  I tried removing the build directory but I still get the error.

Comment: If you've isolated the change to after you did the update. Please edit your question to include as much info about the update that you did. Any console outputs errors. At least the commands you ran. And maybe logs related to the update that might look relevant. This is failing on a cmake sanity check that it can find your compiler. Is your compiler working in another workspace or in a fresh one? Without this info we're really just guessing at what you might have done.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I cannot say for absolute certain that the problem was due to the upgrade (apt get update / apt get upgrade).  It's been a while since I had to build a c++ package and maybe something broke it a while back.  Everything appears to be up to date and am contemplating rebuilding the entire OS installation.

Comment: This stings.  I used DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="w" and not DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-w".  Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Ahhh. Glad that you figured it out. You should be able to post this as an answer to yourself to and I think accept it so that others know that it's resolved.

Comment: This is also a good example of making sure you include a small reproducible example when asking. It would have been much easier to help you if you'd included your build commands where we might have caught this problem. Or you may have even caught it yourself when reproducing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your flags are correct.  In my case, I used DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="w" and not DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-w".  As Tully pointed out, this could have been resolved by posting the command I used to cause the error.  The "w" in the error message kept glaring at me as if it was telling me "hey, dummy, look here."

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting the "build" and "install" folders in your workspace (to remove any pre-existing cmake-generated files), and then running colcon again in this newly cleaned environment?

Comment: Yes, I deleted both and also the "log" folder for the helluva it.